# C how to remove double quotes in a string?

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to remove double quotes using `strtok()` in C. My string contains "b" but I want the double quotes to be removed. Whenever I used `strtok()` all I can remove is the second double quote.

Output:

```
"b
```

Desired Output:

```
b
```

My attempt:

```
strtok(inttbo[ctr].value1, "\"\"");
```

Comment: `strtok` always finds the next token. So you should be using it in a loop if you want to find all tokens.

Comment: provide [mcve].

Comment: Repeating `\"` in the delimiter string doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: The return value from `strtok()` tells you where the first token starts.  The second delimiter has been zapped with a null byte.  The first delimiter probably has not been zapped, which is why it prints.  Be aware that `strtok()` is a poisonous function.

Comment: why do you need to use strtok in this case? If the first character is a quote and there's only one quote in the string then just print from the second character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not the best way, but you can try this.

Since it is C, your string must be stored in an array. So instead of printing it from 0th index, print from first index.

OR

copy string using strncpy to another string from 1st index and then print